# Moq VerifySet fails when using an interface property setter

Tags: mocking, nunit, moq

I have the following code in my Nunit test:

```cs
    [Test]
    public void SmtpSend_UsingSystemCredentials_SetsSmtpClientCredentials()
    {
        const string smtppwd = "smtppwd";
        const string smtpuser = "smtpuser";
        const string smtphost = "smtphost";
        const int smtpport = 333;

        _emailManager.Setup(x => x.ValidateSmtpSettings()).Returns(true);
        _emailTransportConfig.SetupGet(x => x.SmtpPassword).Returns(smtppwd);
        _emailTransportConfig.SetupGet(x => x.SmtpUsername).Returns(smtpuser);
        _emailTransportConfig.SetupGet(x => x.SmtpHost).Returns(smtphost);
        _emailTransportConfig.SetupGet(x => x.SmtpPort).Returns(smtpport);            
        _smtpClient.SetupAllProperties();

        _smtpHandler.Send(null, "from@test.com", "to@test.com", "subject", "body", true);
        _smtpClient.VerifySet(x => x.Port = smtpport);
        _smtpClient.VerifySet(x => x.Host = smtphost);

        // Todo Why is this not working?
        _smtpClient.VerifySet(x => x.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpuser, smtppwd));
    }
```

I can see the code drop into this function:

```cs
private void SetSystemSmtpAccountSettings()
    {           
        _smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential
        {
            UserName = _emailTransportConfig.SmtpUsername,
            Password = _emailTransportConfig.SmtpPassword
        };
        _smtpClient.Host = _emailTransportConfig.SmtpHost;
        _smtpClient.Port = _emailTransportConfig.SmtpPort;
    }
```

But what I can't understand is why the VerifySet invocation fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Daz Lewis said, your `VerifySet` is checking against a different instance.  Instead, try using `It.Is` with a match expression:

```
_smtpClient.VerifySet(x => x.Credentials = It.Is<NetworkCredential>(c => c.UserName == smtpuser && c.Password == smtppwd));
```

Answer (score 2):

You're code sample could use some clarification but I believe your issue lies in the attempt to verify against a `new` NetworkCredential instance which isn't the actual instance set within the method under test hence the verification failure.  It seems that you're trying to verify that the username and password are correctly set on the Credentials property.  This is a state based test more easily verified with a couple of Asserts:

```
Assert.IsNotNull(_smtpClient.Credentials);
Assert.AreEqual(_smtpClient.Credentials.UserName, smtpuser);
Assert.AreEqual(_smtpClient.Credentials.Password, smtppwd);
```

Comment: Hi, I can't test the above as _smtpClient is a Mocked object. I think you are right about it not being able to test against the NetworkCredential instance. How do I resolve that particular issue? I'm testing that the client object is getting properties from one mocked object and setting against another mocked object. Its just the NetworkCredential line which is not working. The other SetupGet/VerifySet pairs are working fine.

Comment: See @adrift's answer - Daz is correct, and that will resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation, but using a factory, so the class that owns credentials is a mock.

```
mockCreate = new Mock<IWebRequestCreate>();
mockRequest = new Mock<WebRequest>();
mockCreate.Setup(x => x.Create(It.IsAny<Uri>()))
                .Returns(mockRequest.Object);
webrequest = new HTTPRequestFactory(mockCreate.Object);
mockRequest.SetupProperty(mr => mr.Credentials);
mockRequest.SetupProperty(mr => mr.Credentials.UserName);
mockRequest.SetupProperty(mr => mr.Credentials.Password);

//setup username and password and send to factory
WebResponse response = webrequest.GetWebResponse(testURI);
mockCreate.VerifyAll();
mockRequest.VerifySet(mr => mr.Credentials = It.Is<NetworkCredential>(c => c.UserName == "user" && c.Password == "password"));
Assert.AreEqual("user", mockRequest.Object.Credentials.UserName);
Assert.AreEqual("user", mockRequest.Object.Credentials.Password);
```

adrifts answer works, Daz's won't compile.  Any hints as to where to look to learn more about why? IntelliSense says it is because `ICredentials` does not have a definition for `UserName` or `Password`.